# mongoose collection.find executed multiple times - into condition & inside if statement

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Inside an express route:

```
// verify if reqUser follows paramsUser
const theFollowing = await Profile_Data.find({
  _id: req.user._id,
  "following": req.params.username
}).lean();

if( req.user && theFollowing ) {
  console.log(theFollowing)
}
```

theFollowing method will be called 2 times because it's used:

1. firstly: as a condition in the if statement
2. secondly: as a block of code inside the if statement

Or just once for the entire route function?

Comment: Please add more details to your question. "theFollowing method will be called 2 times because it's used" is a statement, not a question. "Or just once for the entire route function?" is a question which makes your statement invalid. Please take a few minutes und complete the SO tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour & https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Not to mention that the code makes as it is no sense.

Comment: @Marc I made a new question, [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883048/calling-a-mongodb-request-multiple-times-after-declaring-it-as-an-awaited-variab) . Thanks you! Indeed the question was wrongly asked.