# Calling a MongoDB request multiple times after declaring it as an awaited variable, will result in multiple requests to the database?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

An express app listening for a route includes this code:

```
  const isFollowing = await Profile_Data.exists({
  username: req.user.username,
  following_UserIDs: req.params.username
});

if (isFollowing) { // **first here**
  profile_data["isFollowing"] = isFollowing // **secondly here**
}
```

An awaited variable is making a request to the MongoDB to get a Boolean response. (But the problem might appear in any type of response).
Calling the variable multiple times after declaring it, will result in multiple requests to the Database?

=>A request forEach calling?

In the example above, the `isFollowing` variable is called 2 times. Firstly in the if( condition ), and secondly inside the statement's block code.

Comment: No, this variable is not calling it multiple times. As await helps you to get the data in isFollowing and the value is being used afterwards in the code flow. Is this what you are asking? You should check if this logic is being called multiple times.

Comment: Yes. That is what I was asking for. Thanks you!